# accessing webpage on remote machine from other machines

Tags: apache, wamp, web-hosting, remote-server

I have a webpage hosted using WAMP on my remote machine. I am able to view it from my dev machine by entering the ip address of my rm. I would like to make this page accessible to other team members. How can I give the page a domain name and make it accessible to others?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your organization then you can probably contact network team who will help you setting up the domain name. The domain name should point to the IP address of your remote machine.
If this is your private project and would like your team members to access webpage via internet, you could probably go with domain name registrars such as GoDaddy etc. [Check here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-a-great-domain-registrar-company) to explore few options. You will need to make sure that your remote machine is able to receive  web traffic over the port 80 for HTTP and/or 443 HTTPS.
 You can refer this as well [Using domain name with WAMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RoSh1HJCO8)